# Reference error: object not defined DataGridView value to TextBox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, referenceerror

I'm working on an app in which I have a form where I enter data to a textbox from a DataGridView when textbox event leave.

[image]

Ok, now, when I enter number 1 in the textbox, the value for that # in row automatically get in the txtbox. Or if I type 2, the value for #2 row enters in that txtbox.
Problem is when I enter number '0', I get Reference Error: Object not defined.

Here is the code:

```
            Dim txt = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        Dim numero As Integer

        If Int32.TryParse(txt.Text, numero) Then
            Dim fila = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().
                FirstOrDefault(Function(c) Convert.ToInt32(c.Cells(0).Value) = numero)

            If fila IsNot Nothing Then
                txt.Text = fila.Cells(1).Value.ToString() <---ERROR LINE

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Value number not found")
                ResColorTextBox.Clear()
                ResColorTextBox.Focus()
            End If
        End If
```

The error goes in the line 'txt.Text = fila.Cells(1).Value.ToString()'

Everything goes good, if I enter a number that is not in the DGV for # column msgsbox shows OK, but not number zero.

How can I solve this?

Comment: That seems to suggest that the `Value` of the cell is `Nothing`.  You can't call `ToString` on an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ty for reply  jmcilhinney.
Well, Ok, I understand what you mean, but, why If I leave Textbox empty, error doesn't showup?

I tried removing ToString, It seems to work well, but I don't knwo if in the future I'll have issues

Comment: This issue has nothing whatsoever to do with the `TextBox`. If you get the `Value` from a cell and try to access any property or method of that object when that object doesn't exist then you'll get a `NullReeferenceException`. It doesn't matter what member you're trying to access and it doesn't matter what you're trying to do with the result of that member. As is always the case, the thing to do if the `Value` might be `Nothing` is to actually check whether it is `Nothing` first and then only use it if it's not.

Comment: Thx very much mate. It's been much help. Best regards